# How can I coordinate Memory access between the host JS and the Wasm module?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, webassembly

At present, Webassembly only supports [a handful of parameter types](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Semantics.md#types), namely fixed sized integers and floating point numbers. This means that I can only define and export functions from my C/Rust modules that accept and return numeric values.

However, [according to the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory), I can manipulate the module's memory from the host Javascript:

> [M]emory created by JavaScript or in WebAssembly code will be accessible and mutable from both JavaScript and WebAssembly.

This sounds very promising--it indicates that I could designate part of the memory as a byte buffer in which to shuttle more complex data back and forth across the language barrier. Functions in my module could accept and return pointers (which are themselves `i32`, fixed size integers), thereby working within the current constraints.

Unfortunately, it is not clear how I should go about managing this memory. If I need to pass data to the Wasm process from JS, I need to write to the Memory object directly but won't know which regions in the Memory are free.

What's the safest strategy? Should I export a pair of `malloc`-and-`free`-style functions that give the JS a way to request memory before calls into Wasm? Or is there an established best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest thing is to use Emscripten, and use its built-in malloc / free. Then export a function which, in C++, allocates the memory requested through that malloc / free, and returns the pointer. That way JavaScript can call into WebAssembly to get a usable memory region which isn't already used.

I've detailed how to share strings to / from JS / wasm in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353389/how-can-i-return-a-javascript-string-from-a-web-assembly-function/41372484#41372484), which has details on some of the above.

Note that pointers in WebAssembly aren't really a thing. C++ simply maps them to the Memory, which starts at 0. So when you index the ArrayBuffer you just need the pointer from C++, no extra mapping required.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I notice that emscripten's `malloc` implementation can trigger the `grow_memory` operation. Do you happen to know if that would invalidate any pointers already issued? Or does that process preserve the original memory layout?

Comment: Though you can configure Emscripten to never grow, always preallocate and fail if it goes OOM.

Comment: How does one discover that an ArrayBuffer has been invalidated? Does accessing it in JS cause an exception? (Or have I misunderstood your use of 'neuter'?)

Comment: Sorry, detach is what I should have said. As soon as it succeeds in growing it'll do that. I don't believe Emscripen will tell you though! The `byteLength` will become `0` on detach. WebAssembly details on this:  https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblymemoryprototypegrow

Comment: Thanks for the docs, very helpful. It sounds as though the ArrayBuffer itself will be truncated to a length of zero, but any makeshift `i32` pointers I have would still be valid if used on the replacement buffer.

Comment: Correct, the pointer are still valid because they are indices into the Memory / ArrayBuffer. The underlying virtual memory may move, but that's invisible from WebAssembly / JavaScript.