# unresolved symbol: llvm_trap from Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, webassembly

When I tried to compile the following snippet into WebAssembly binary, I kept hitting the `unresolved symbol: llvm_trap` warning, which makes the wasm code not consumable from JS.

```
emcc test.c -s WASM=1 -s ONLY_MY_CODE=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_test']" -O2 -g -o test.js
```

**test.c** (This is a test code to reproduce the issue without doing meaningful jobs.)

```
int test(int *buf) {
  int C = 1;
  // Assuming WebAssembly.Memory buffer has been preloaed with data. 
  // *T represents the preloaded data here. And We know *T and *buf 
  // won't overlap in memory.
  int *T = 0; 

  int index = C ^ buf[5];
  int right = T[index];
  int left = (unsigned)C >> 8;

  // warning disappears if this is commented out. But why?
  C = left ^ right; 

  return C;
}
```

I didn't write any `llvm_trap` related code. Does someone have ideas what does it mean?

Comment: This is wrong because `T` is NULL. `int right = T[index];`.

Comment: @MFisherKDX In WebAssembly, we can preload data to `WebAssembly.Memory` buffer. `*T` here is simply a pointer to the specific position in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `T` must be initialised. If it represents an array that 'maps' to the WebAssembly linear memory, you can define it as a global as follows:

```
int T[1000];

int test(int *buf) {
  int C = 1;

  int index = C ^ buf[5];
  int right = T[index];
  int left = (unsigned)C >> 8;

  // warning disappears if this is commented out. But why?
  C = left ^ right;

  return C;
}
```

This compiles without the llvm_trap warnings.

For more detail on how to pass data to a WASM function using linear memory, see the following question:

[How to access WebAssembly linear memory from C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748572/how-to-access-webassembly-linear-memory-from-c-c)