# Call XmlHttpRequest from WebAssembly

Tags: xmlhttprequest, webassembly

I try to understand what the best and most efficient way is to call XmlHttpRequest from WebAssembly.

I found http://webassembly.org/getting-started/js-api/ which seems to explain how to make calls between JavaScript and WebAssembly.

In order for getting this to work it seems to me I have to do the following:

- Write a JavaScript function that I import into WebAssembly which calls XmlHttpRequest
- Write a WebAssembly function that I export from WebAssembly which JavaScript calls when the XmlHttpRequest is complete.

In case I want to have a dynamic number of concurrent XmlHttpRequests running, I would also need the imported function to provide a handler that is then provided back by JavaScript to the exported function.

I now have a number of questions:

1. Is the above accurate and the way to do it?
2. How do I transfer the URI from WebAssembly to XmlHttpRequest? Do I have to either import or export a WebAssembler.Memory object to/from WebAssembly and place the URI in that?
3. If the answer to 2 is yes, this WebAssembler.Memory object will be like a global-variable but this can work because there is only one thread. Correct?
4. Similar to 2, how do I transfer the result of the XmlHttpRequest back to WebAssembly? Also in an imported/exported WebAssembler.Memory object?
5. In connection with 4, how do I get the result of the XmlHttpRequest into WebAssembly in the most efficient way - e.g. with as few copies as possible? Do I need to copy the result of XmlHttpRequest into the WebAssembler.Memory object from the JavaScript code? And again, this WebAssembler.Memory object is a global variable? I guess I could let the call form WebAssembly to JavaScript pass an index to indicate where in WebAssember.Memory the result should be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, this is correct.
2. You can transfer URIs as strings, as explained in [this question about strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353389/how-can-i-return-a-javascript-string-from-a-webassembly-function)
3. When WebAssembly supports threads, you'd call out to JavaScript and could just heap-allocate the string, pass out its pointer+length, and delete on return from that call.
4. Yes, transfer it back like a string.
5. Currently you have to do a copy, though the Community Group is discussing ways that would allow fewer copies to occur in the future. The notes for the latest such discussion [are available from the WebAssembly meetings repository](https://github.com/WebAssembly/meetings/blob/master/2017/CG-11.md#javascript-bindings-for-webassembly).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this was very useful! A follow up:
When compiling from C, I understand there is always a WebAssembly.Memory instance shared between JavaScript and WebAssembly which is the memory used by the C program.
Is it possible to share an additional WebAssembly.Memory instance? How would that look from the C side? I think this could be useful so that JavaScript could allocate its own memory for the response from HttpXmlRequest and then pass that to WebAssembly.

Comment: Currently WebAssembly only supports a single memory. There are plans to support more in the future. It would be up to toolchains to expose it how they see fit. LLVM has IR for `addrspace` which would do this, and some languages use it in LLVM. In C++ allocators were made for something similar (segmentation), but one would have to write code to do this.