# Is it valid to use ptr::NonNull in FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi, abi, non-nullable

Rust has the [`ptr::NonNull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html) type that represents a non-`NULL` pointer. Is it safe to use this type in FFI?

Is it guaranteed to have same binary representation (ignoring non-FFI context such as `Option` optimizations), alignment, register usage as `*mut T`?

For example, could I implement this interface:

```c
void call_me_from_c(char *without_nulls) __attribute__((nonnull));
```

with

```
extern "C" fn call_me_from_c(without_nulls: ptr::NonNull<c_char>)
```

I don't expect this to *do* anything (apart from causing UB when misused with `NULL` ;), but I would like the interface to document that the function requires non-`NULL` arguments.

Comment: Rust issue for this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49220

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what version of Rust you are compiling with.

#### Rust 1.29 and up

`NonNull` [now has `repr(transparent)`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.29.0/src/libcore/ptr.rs#L2846-L2850), so it is safe to use in FFI so long as the wrapped type is safe.

```
#[stable(feature = "nonnull", since = "1.25.0")]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct NonNull<T: ?Sized> {
    pointer: NonZero<*const T>,
}
```

#### Before Rust 1.29

I would *not* use it for such. The main reason is due to [its definition](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.28.0/src/libcore/ptr.rs#L2842-L2845):

```
#[stable(feature = "nonnull", since = "1.25.0")]
pub struct NonNull<T: ?Sized> {
    pointer: NonZero<*const T>,
}
```

More specifically, I'm concerned about what's *not* in the definition: [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation) (emphasis mine):

> Structs with this representation have the **same layout and ABI** as the single non-zero sized field.

I've experienced miscompilation due to [putting newtypes in a FFI function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49020435/155423) that were solved by `repr(transparent)`, so this isn't just an academic exercise.

Comment: In this case, `repr(C)` would be enough, since `NonNull` is not a newtype, however, since it's neither marked as `repr(C)` nor as `repr(transparent)` it isn't safe.

Comment: @Tim would you share why you say its not a newtype? it's a struct of a single field, which is the key component of a newtype AFAIK.

Comment: I assumed newtypes are structs of the form `struct Foo(Bar);` but correct me, if I got this wrong. At least in all literature I read so far, the term "Newtype" was in this context.