# How to read a file with JavaScript to WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly

How can I pass a `File` to be read within the WebAssembly memory context?

Reading a file in the browser with JavaScript is easy:

```
<input class="file-selector" type="file" id="files" name="files[]" />
```

I was able to bootstrap WebAssembly code written in Rust with the crate [stdweb](https://github.com/koute/stdweb), add an event listener to the DOM element and fire up a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText):

```
let reader = FileReader::new();
let file_input_element: InputElement = document().query_selector(".file-selector").unwrap().unwrap().try_into().unwrap();
file_input_element.add_event_listener(enclose!( (reader, file_input_element) move |event: InputEvent| {
    // mystery part
}));
```

In JavaScript, I would get the file from the element and pass it to the reader, however, the API of stdweb needs the following signature:

```
pub fn read_as_array_buffer<T: IBlob>(&self, blob: &T) -> Result<(), TODO>
```

I have no idea how to implement `IBlob` and I am sure that I am missing something obvious either with the stdweb API or in my understanding of WebAssembly/Rust. I was hoping that there is something less verbose than [converting stuff to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014610/passing-a-javascript-string-to-a-rust-function-compiled-to-webassembly).

Comment: Maybe stdweb doesn't have clean way to access `InputElement.files` now. https://github.com/koute/stdweb/commit/3b85c941db00b8e3c942624afd50c5929085fb08

Comment: See also this [bug report](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1727) about reading files with wasm-bindgen. It contains some pointers that might help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works when the `FileReader` itself is passed from JavaScript to WebAssembly. It also seems like a clean approach because the data has to be read by the JavaScript API anyway - no need to call JS from WASM.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Read to wasm</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file-input"/>
<script src="reader.js"></script>
<script>
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = e => Rust.reader
            .then(reader=> {
                window.alert(reader.print_result(fileReader));
            });

    var fileInputElement = document.getElementById("file-input");
    fileInputElement.addEventListener("change", e => fileReader.readAsText(fileInputElement.files[0]));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.rs**

```
#![feature(proc_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate stdweb;

use stdweb::js_export;
use stdweb::web::FileReader;
use stdweb::web::FileReaderResult;

#[js_export]
fn print_result(file_reader: FileReader) -> String {
    match file_reader.result() {
        Some(value) => match value {
            FileReaderResult::String(value) => value,
            _ => String::from("not a text"),
        }
        None => String::from("empty")
    }
}

fn main() {
    stdweb::initialize();

    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

Comment: Is `reader.js` the name of the WASM module the `main.rs` gets packaged into?

Comment: @EricH yes I think so. Not sure after two years :D. There also might be better a better way to do this now.

Answer (score 4):

The following code is what I use to interact with another javascript library to read a sql file all without using javascript. This is based on the wasm-bindgen library, and I believe may be helpful to newer folks stumbling onto this answer.

```
[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn load_accounts_from_file_with_balances(file_input : web_sys::HtmlInputElement) {
    //Check the file list from the input
    let filelist = file_input.files().expect("Failed to get filelist from File Input!");
    //Do not allow blank inputs
    if filelist.length() < 1 {
        alert("Please select at least one file.");
        return;
    }
    if filelist.get(0) == None {
        alert("Please select a valid file");
        return;
    }
    
    let file = filelist.get(0).expect("Failed to get File from filelist!");

    let file_reader : web_sys::FileReader = match web_sys::FileReader::new() {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => {
            alert("There was an error creating a file reader");
            log(&JsValue::as_string(&e).expect("error converting jsvalue to string."));
            web_sys::FileReader::new().expect("")
        }
    };

    let fr_c = file_reader.clone();
    // create onLoadEnd callback
    let onloadend_cb = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |_e: web_sys::ProgressEvent| {
        let array = js_sys::Uint8Array::new(&fr_c.result().unwrap());
        let len = array.byte_length() as usize;
        log(&format!("Blob received {}bytes: {:?}", len, array.to_vec()));
        // here you can for example use the received image/png data
        
        let db : Database = Database::new(array);

        //Prepare a statement
        let stmt : Statement = db.prepare(&sql_helper_utility::sql_load_accounts_with_balances());
        stmt.getAsObject();

        // Bind new values
        stmt.bind();

        while stmt.step() { //
            let row = stmt.getAsObject();
            log(&("Here is a row: ".to_owned() + &stringify(row).to_owned()));
        }

    }) as Box<dyn Fn(web_sys::ProgressEvent)>);

    file_reader.set_onloadend(Some(onloadend_cb.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    file_reader.read_as_array_buffer(&file).expect("blob not readable");
    onloadend_cb.forget();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to access the file object and pass it to the `FileReader`in the following way:

```
let reader = FileReader::new();
let file_input_element: InputElement = document()
    .query_selector(".file-selector")
    .unwrap()
    .unwrap()
    .try_into()
    .unwrap();

file_input_element.add_event_listener(
    enclose!( (reader, file_input_element) move |event: InputEvent| {
        let file = js!{return @{&file_input_element}.files[0]};
        let real_file: stdweb::web::Blob = file.try_into().unwrap();

        reader.read_as_text(&real_file);
    }
```

This code compiles. However, the data never gets available via `reader.result()`.