# Getting error while using #[js_export] from crate stdweb

Tags: rust, rust-wasm

I need to read client file in a rust-wasm program and I am trying two solution given on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231915 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69305956/4466255. Both these solutions are accepted and given bounties so I am assuming they work.

both of these have used following code

```
use stdweb::js_export
#[js_export]
```

But when i try to compile these codes I got following error

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `__web_free` in module `stdweb::private`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
14 | #[js_export]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `stdweb::private`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `js_export` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What I am missing. How can we make it work?

My current code, which I have taken from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231915, in lib.rs is

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate stdweb;

use stdweb::js_export;
use stdweb::web::FileReader;
use stdweb::web::FileReaderResult;

#[js_export]
fn print_result(file_reader: FileReader) -> String {
    match file_reader.result() {
        Some(value) => match value {
            FileReaderResult::String(value) => value,
            _ => String::from("not a text"),
        }
        None => String::from("empty")
    }
}

pub fn test_reader() {
    stdweb::initialize();

    stdweb::event_loop();
}
```

and the Cargo.toml file is

```
[package]
name = "read-file2"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["kushdesh"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[features]
default = ["console_error_panic_hook"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.63"
stdweb = "0.4.20"

console_error_panic_hook = { version = "0.1.6", optional = true }

wee_alloc = { version = "0.4.5", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
wasm-bindgen-test = "0.3.13"

[profile.release]
# Tell `rustc` to optimize for small code size.
opt-level = "s"
```

Comment: What does your build process look like? Are you using wasm-pack?

Comment: Yes, I am using command 'wasm-pack build' to compile

Comment: Have you tried the [`cargo-web`](https://github.com/koute/cargo-web) subcommand instead? I believe it was specifically made to be used with `stdweb`.