# Returning a Rust Vec<Vec<i32>> to JavaScript via WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, pointers, rust, webassembly

I am working on a project involving Rust and WebAssembly using the "wasm32-unknown-unknown" target. It is no problem to return a `Vec<i32>` from my Rust code using this function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn calc_vector() -> usize {
    unsafe {
        vec_len = 0;
    }

    let mut data: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..1000 {
        data.push(i);
    }

    unsafe {
        vec_len = data.len();
    }

    data.as_mut_ptr() as usize
}
```

This returns an offset and I call another function from JS to get the length of my `Vec`. I then build the Vector in JavaScript again (knowing that `i32` -> 4x `uint8`):

```
let vec_addr = exports.calc_vector();
let vec_len = exports.get_vec_len();

while(arr.length < vec_len) {
    let numberUint8 = new DataView(view.buffer, vec_addr, 4);
    let number = numberUint8.getInt32(0, true);
    arr.push(number)

    // move to next value in vector
    vec_addr += 4;
}
```

Using this, I want to create a Rust function that returns a `Vec<Vec<i32>>`, however, it just won't work:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn calc_vector_in_vector() -> usize {
    unsafe {
        vec_len = 0;
        elements_in_vect = 0;
    }

    let mut outer_vec: Vec<*mut i32> = Vec::new();
    let mut inner_vec: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..100 {
        inner_vec.push(i);
        unsafe {
            elements_in_vect += 1;
        }
    }

    outer_vec.push(inner_vec.as_mut_ptr());

    unsafe {
        vec_len = outer_vec.len();
    }

    outer_vec.as_mut_ptr() as usize
}
```

I thought that I could use the same logic as with a single `Vec`: at the address returned from `calc_vector_in_vector()` is the first entry of the outer vector, containing the address as `i32` of the first element of the inner vector (an actual number). However, on this address there seems to be nonsense. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure how the first example works. You are returning a pointer to a value which immediately goes out of scope. I haven't used wasm, but I guess the way to do this is to allocate a buffer in Javascript, and fill the buffer from Rust. That way, Javascript owns the data and it won't go out of scope.

Comment: Please see [How to return a string (or similar) from Rust in WebAssembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47529643/155423) to learn how to correctly return one `Vec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the vectors in my vector are all the same length, I can use the lazy_static crate to initialize a static `Vec` wrapped in a `Mutex` (to be able to alter it later on). `LEN_VEC` is the length of the vector and `SIZE_INNER_VEC` the size of one vector in my static vector.

I then add `i32` to the static vector and return the address of the `Vec` using `ARRAY.lock().unwrap().as_mut_ptr() as usize`. With `SIZE_INNER_VEC` and `LEN_VEC`, I can recreate the vectors in my vector in JavaScript.

```
static mut LEN_VEC: usize = 0;
static mut SIZE_INNER_VEC: usize = 0;

lazy_static! {
    // Wrap in Mutex to change later on
    static ref ARRAY: Mutex<Vec<i32>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

pub fn vector_in_vector() -> usize {
    //set LEN_VEC
    //set SIZE_INNER_VEC

    ARRAY.lock().unwrap().as_mut_ptr() as usize
}
```