# How do I access a wasm modules memory when its loaded by webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to follow

[How to return a string (or similar) from Rust in WebAssembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529643/how-to-return-a-string-or-similar-from-rust-in-webassembly)

Which allows accessing String data inside a wasm module.

I have used `wasm-pack build` to build a RUST module and I can access the methods exported but not the memory directly.

The webpack generated JavScript has a method that allows me to read Strings

```
function getStringFromWasm(ptr, len) {
    return cachedTextDecoder.decode(getUint8Memory().subarray(ptr, ptr + len));
}
```

but it is not exported, if I hack this generated .js file to

```
export function getStringFromWasm(ptr, len)
```

I can access Strings returned by RUST code.

How can I configure the webpack code generator to give me similar access, or otherwise expose the module's `exports.memory`?

Webpack does not seem to give me a handle on the module itself.  I cant find a way to load the `.wasm` file webpack generates with `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()` since it seems to rely on the other generated files.