# Calling a WASM function that returns a string from Wasmtime

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-wasm, wasmtime

At a high level I am trying to create a Rust host program that loads a WASM module at runtime using Wasmtime and calls a WASM function that returns a string.  I can get this working with numeric types such as `usize`, but can't work out how to handle strings (or other complex types).

In my plugin crate I have a `lib.rs` that I compile with `cargo build --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown --release`:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

static PLUGIN_NAME: &'static str = "Test Plugin";

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn plugin_name() -> *mut c_char {
    let s = CString::new(PLUGIN_NAME).unwrap();
    s.into_raw()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn plugin_name_len() -> usize {
    PLUGIN_NAME.len()
}
```

This is based on code in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529643/how-to-return-a-string-or-similar-from-rust-in-webassembly) which is close to what I'm looking for, but uses JavaScript on the host side.

In my host crate I have a `main.rs`:

```rust
use wasmtime::{Engine, Linker, Module, Store};
use wasmtime_wasi::WasiCtxBuilder;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let engine = Engine::default();

    let Some(file) = std::env::args().nth(1) else {
        anyhow::bail!("USAGE: host <WASM FILE>");
    };

    let module = Module::from_file(&engine, file)?;

    let linker = Linker::new(&engine);
    let wasi = WasiCtxBuilder::new()
        .inherit_stdio()
        .inherit_args()
        .expect("should always be able to inherit args")
        .build();
    let mut store = Store::new(&engine, wasi);

    let instance = linker.instantiate(&mut store, &module)?;

    let Ok(plugin_name_len) = instance.get_typed_func::<(), u32>(&mut store, "plugin_name_len") else {
        anyhow::bail!("Failed to get plugin_name_len");
    };

    let len = plugin_name_len.call(&mut store, ())?;
    println!("Length: {}", len);

    let Ok(plugin_name) = instance.get_typed_func::<(), &str>(&mut store, "plugin_name") else {
        anyhow::bail!("Failed to get plugin_name");
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

But that doesn't compile as you can't use `&str` in a call to `instance.get_typed_func()`

Could someone share an example (and an explanation) of how to call a WASM function that returns a string from a Rust Wasmtime host program?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can only transfer simple types between WASM and JavaScript. Five years ago the only way to transfer a string was to write it down in WASM's memory as a sequence of bytes and transfer the address. Then assemble a new native string on the other end from bytes by directly reading WASM's memory at the specified address. Maybe wasmtime already has something for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got this working.

The TL;DR is that the plugin WASM function `plugin_name()` returns a 32-bit integer which is effectively a pointer into the WASM memory.  To access the WASM memory you need to get a Wasmtime [`Memory`](https://docs.rs/wasmtime/latest/wasmtime/struct.Memory.html) struct by accessing the `"memory"` export from your `Instance`.  You can then use the 32-bit integer you got from your call to `plugin_name()` as the offset to the first character of your string and this offset + the length of your string as the last character.  Convert this slice of `u8`s into a Vec and feed it into `String::from_utf8()` and you've got a `String`!

Updated, working, `main.rs`:

```rust
use wasmtime::{Engine, Linker, Module, Store};
use wasmtime_wasi::WasiCtxBuilder;

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let engine = Engine::default();

    let Some(file) = std::env::args().nth(1) else {
        anyhow::bail!("USAGE: host <WASM FILE>");
    };

    let module = Module::from_file(&engine, file)?;

    let linker = Linker::new(&engine);
    let wasi = WasiCtxBuilder::new()
        .inherit_stdio()
        .inherit_args()
        .expect("should always be able to inherit args")
        .build();
    let mut store = Store::new(&engine, wasi);

    let instance = linker.instantiate(&mut store, &module)?;

    let Ok(plugin_name_len) = instance.get_typed_func::<(), u32>(&mut store, "plugin_name_len") else {
        anyhow::bail!("Failed to get plugin_name_len");
    };
    let len = plugin_name_len.call(&mut store, ())? as usize;

    let Ok(plugin_name) = instance.get_typed_func::<(), u32>(&mut store, "plugin_name") else {
        anyhow::bail!("Failed to get plugin_name");
    };
    let ptr = plugin_name.call(&mut store, ())? as usize;

    let Some(memory) = instance.get_memory(&mut store, "memory") else {
        anyhow::bail!("Failed to get WASM memory");
    };

    let data = memory.data(&store)[ptr..(ptr + len)].to_vec();
    let name = String::from_utf8(data)?;
    println!("Plugin name: {}", name);

    Ok(())
}
```

Note - I'm converting `len` and `ptr` from `u32` to `usize` so that I can use them to index into the WASM memory from Rust.