# Transfer byte array (Uint8Array) between WebAssembly and JavaScript

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

I have a u8[] array in WebAssembly code, how can I read it in regular JS? Calls to it just return me a i32.

```
// Load module WebAssembly.Instance
const instance = await getInstance("./build/embed.wasm");

// Try to get the array of bytes from the module
const embeddedFileBytes = Uint8Array.from(instance.fileBytes);

// write the file to disc
await writeFile("./output.text", embeddedFileBytes);

// check the hash is the same as the original file that was embedded
expect(sha1("./output.text")).toEqual(sha1("./input.text"))
```

The webassembly module has an export:

```
export const fileBytes: u8[] = [83,65,77,80,76,69,10];
```

Comment: Can you provide any sample code of your work? Otherwise I cannot show an example.

Comment: Added an example code thanks @BumsikKim

Comment: Thanks, but what is that WebAssembly module written in? And is it just a one-liner? Also what is `getInstance()`? It is not a standard WebAssembly API, so what kind of library you used for the JS code? Since you are already not using a "regular JS", please provide a more specific context...

Comment: Note that it is not just about WebAssembly anymore but a question about your framework for WebAssembly. So you probably want to add additional tags in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAssembly is a low level virtual machine that only supports numeric types. More complex types, such as as strings, structs and arrays, are encoded within the WebAssembly's [linear memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API#Memory) - which is a contiguous block of memory that both WebAssembly and JavaScript can read and write to.

The value returned by `fileBytes` isn't the array itself, it is instead a pointer to the location of the array in linear memory. In order to obtain the data from the array, you'll need to read it from linear memory - in much the same way as you would read a string, as described in the following question:

[How can I return a JavaScript string from a WebAssembly function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353389/how-can-i-return-a-javascript-string-from-a-webassembly-function)

If you don't want to write this 'glue' code yourself, I'd recommend looking into [wasm-bindgen](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen)

Comment: Thanks, the penny droped and I understand now. I examned the 'glue' available in WebAssembly/binaryen and was able to find a method (`__getUint8Array`) to extract the bytes using their loader